# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'

Tags: node.js, angular, form-control

here is my import

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpService } from ".././http.service";
import { FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
```

this is how i initialized my forms

```
emailFormControl = new FormControl("", [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.email
  ]);

  nameFormControl = new FormControl("", [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(4)
  ]);
```

and this is my send function

```
send() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.buttonText = "Submiting...";
    let user = {
      name: this.nameFormControl.value,
      email: this.emailFormControl.value
    }
    this.http.sendnotif("http://localhost:8080/send-notif", user).subscribe(
      data => {
        let res:any = data;
        console.log(
          `an email has been sent successfully to  ${user.name}  and the message id is ${res.messageId}`
        );
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
        this.loading = false;
        this.buttonText = "Submit";
      },() => {
        this.loading = false;
        this.buttonText = "Submit";
      }
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the html

```
<form style="width: 50%; margin: auto">
  <mat-card>
    <h1>Please fill the form </h1>

    <mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
      <input matInput placeholder="Name" [formControl]="nameFormControl" />
      <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('minlength')">
        Name must be at least 4 characters long.
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="nameFormControl.hasError('required')">
        Name is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field style="width: 100%">
      <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="emailFormControl"/>
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('email')">
        Please enter a valid email address
      </mat-error>
      <mat-error *ngIf="emailFormControl.hasError('required')">
        Email is <strong>required</strong>
      </mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>

    <button
      mat-raised-button
      [disabled]="emailFormControl.invalid || nameFormControl.invalid || loading"
      color="primary"
      (click)="send()"
    >
      {{buttonText}}
    </button>
  </mat-card>
</form>
```

and the error i'm recieving is "Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'FormControl'." and it is pointing on "http://localhost:8080/send-notif"
any suggestions how i can solve this i pretty much tried everything

Comment: Can you share the full source of the controller (ts/html) ?

Comment: @robert i have added the html thank u

Comment: Have you added `import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` to module?

Comment: @robert yeah i've added that too but still i got the same error

Comment: Can you create a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: @robert i have deleted the whole component and i wrote it again so no errors now except for the cors one

Comment: As a sanity check, if you change the `form` element to a doc you still get the same result, right?